# Disable "No Internet Access" warning on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7

I have a number of Windows 7 machines on an isolated development network.  There is no internet access from this network.

Winodws 7 displays a yellow warning triangle on the network connection icon with a warning "No Internet Access".

Is there anyway to disable this warning - I *know* the internet is inaccessable and always will be.

Answer (score 1):

If its on a pc by pc basis you could go to the Task Bar - Click customize and set the Network to Hide Icon and Notifications. That would stop the notification showing.

Comment: True - but that also hides any notifications if the network cable is unplugged (or the local network unreachable) which I do want to know about.